# check if geo coordinates are in dynamically drawn polygon

Tags: google-maps, gis, geospatial, geo

I'm trying to do point(s) in polygon implementation with multiple points and dynamic shapes drawn over google maps. The user may draw a shape over a map and tries to find all stored places(available in database as lat and long) in that drawn shape.

I've browsed enough articles and SO posts on how they store the borders of the polygon into a table and doing a spatial query which doesn't suit my problem. In my case it is dynamic input.

I'm looking for an optimal way to do this instead of storing the shapes. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try browser based spatial analytics libraries for point-in-polygon algorithms e.g http://turfjs.org/ or http://geoscript.org/.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out some of the alternative ways. Really good to know.